# Does @@identity return the primary key or identity field?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

My issue is that I've got update triggers on an SQL View (MS SQL 2005) which I'm mapping to LINQ to SQL entities in C#...

My SQL looks correct but it complains about trying to insert a null value into a secondary table PK field.

I believe my issue relates to having the primary key and identity as separate fields in the primary table. So my question is this....when using @@identity, does it look at the primary key of the inserted row, or does it look at the field with "IDENTITY" specified???

Comment: Why would anyone ever have an identity field that wasn't the primary key? If you have a natural key, set a unique undex on it and use the identity filed as the PK. It will imporve performance and make updates to the natural key (and there are alawys updates to natural keys even if just to fix a typo) easier as they won't have to filter through all the child records.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@@IDENTITY` only returns the identity value from the last insert. It has no idea whether that value was used in a primary key column or even if it is going to be unique for the given column. Rather than using `@@IDENTITY`, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` especially if you have triggers. @@IDENTITY only cares about the column (there can only be one on a table) that has the IDENTITY attribute. Whether the table has a primary key or not and whether the PK is the identity column makes no difference.

See [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) for more.

Comment: Strongly agree, but use scope_identity even if you don't have triggers, you don't know when someone might add them later and you can't risk data integrity errors that are all but impossible to fix.

Comment: +1 @@IDENTITY, is the last identity inserted in any scope (from inside a trigger or anywhere, just the last one), SCOPE_IDENTITY() gives you the last one in the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`  instead of `@@Identity`

Answer (score 0):

@@IDENTITY always references the identity column, never at a table's primary key. (How would that work if it were a compound primary key?) As Thomas says, since you are working with triggers, you should probably be using SCOPE_IDENTITY().